# How to get jdbc connection from railo datasource pool

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, railo

I am using Railo with Postgres and need to map custom Postgres data type to a class, eg (from Postgres doc):

```
((org.postgresql.Connection)myconn).addDataType("mytype","my.class.name");
```

This need to be performed for all connections in the pool.
The problem is, how do I get the connection objects from the datasource pool?
Seems that connection is created and added to the pool lazily, is it possible to add an event handler for each connection creation?

Thanks